# Sum of selected values in an int Array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, sum, integer

I'm learning how to program using c#. I'm really new to this.
My question is I'm trying to create an array that shows 10 numbers. I want my code to check which numbers below 10 are divisible for 3 or 5 and sum the total.
I've tried to use the .Sum() function but says int doesn't contain a definition for Sum. I've put using System.Linq on my program.
Does anyone have an idea how to make this sum happens?

```
        {

            int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
            int sum = 1 + 2;
            

            foreach (int n in numbers)
            {
                if (n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0)
                {
                    int total = n.Sum();
                     Console.WriteLine(total);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("not divisible");
                }
            }`
```

Comment: Looks like a FizzBuzz sort of assignment. It's not clear what exactly led you to the code you have now. If you want the sum of the _whole_ array, why would you try to compute it and print it _during_ the loop over the array elements? If you are allowed to use LINQ (which `Sum()` is a part of), then you may want, instead of the loop, a call to `Where()`. But it's not entirely clear what the final goal is here, nor what kind of help would be best for this apparent homework assignment.

Comment: Hi @Yorda, please remember to accept an answer and upvote if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correct and using your code this is what you want.

```
        int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        int sum = 1 + 2;
        int total=0;

        foreach (int n in numbers)
        {
            if (n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0)
            {
                int total += n;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("not divisible");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(total);
```

I moved the printing out to after the foreach so you get one result when it is done

Answer (score 1):

So your problem is that you are trying to call `.Sum()` on a variable `n` which is of type `int` (you define it here: `foreach (int n in numbers)`, and that is not a method.

Using LINQ you could do something like:

```
var numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
var total = numbers.Where(n => n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0).Sum();
```

Comment: `.Sum()` is a LINQ extension method defined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

Everybody forgot that array should contain 10 numbers  but some numbers values maybe greater than 10. Only number values  below 10 should  be checked. So a right answer should be

```
var numbers = new int[] { 1, 9, 5, 6, 8, 10,4, 15, 25, 3};
var total = numbers.Where( n => (n<10) && ( n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0)).Sum();
```